# Bot framework Single Tenant Bot to Skill communication

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to run a sample at https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot/README.md using Single Tenant mode and App ID and password in the bot emulator. I kept getting UnAuthorized error. After some digging thorugh the documentation, adding below lines of configuration helped to overcome the UnAuthorized error.

```
    "OAuthUrl": "https://unitedstates.api.botframework.com",
      "ToChannelFromBotOAuthScope": "https://api.botframework.com",
      "ToChannelFromBotLoginUrlTemplate": "https://api.botframework.com",
      "PublicAzureChannel": "https://api.botframework.com",
      "ToBotFromChannelOpenIdMetadataUrl": "https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration",
      "ToBotFromEmulatorOpenIdMetadataUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
      "ToBotFromChannelTokenIssuer": "https://api.botframework.com",
      "ToChannelFromBotLoginUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com"
```

After that truing to call the skill gives following error.

```
`"label": "TurnError",
  "valueType": "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
  "value": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error invoking the skill id: "label": "TurnError",
  "valueType": "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
  "value": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error invoking the skill id: \"EchoSkillBot\" at \"http://localhost:39783/api/messages\" (status is 500). 
 Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10208: Unable to validate audience. validationParameters.ValidAudience is null or whitespace and validationParameters.ValidAudiences is null.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.JwtTokenExtractor.ValidateTokenAsync(String jwtToken, String channelId, String[] requiredEndorsements)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.JwtTokenExtractor.GetIdentityAsync(String scheme, String parameter, String channelId, String[] requiredEndorsements)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.JwtTokenExtractor.GetIdentityAsync(String authorizationHeader, String channelId, String[] requiredEndorsements)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ParameterizedBotFrameworkAuthentication.SkillValidation_AuthenticateChannelTokenAsync(String authHeader, String channelId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ParameterizedBotFrameworkAuthentication.JwtTokenValidation_AuthenticateTokenAsync(String authHeader, String channelId, String serviceUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ParameterizedBotFrameworkAuthentication.JwtTokenValidation_ValidateAuthHeaderAsync(String authHeader, String channelId, String serviceUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ParameterizedBotFrameworkAuthentication.JwtTokenValidation_AuthenticateRequestAsync(Activity activity, String authHeader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ParameterizedBotFrameworkAuthentication.AuthenticateRequestAsync(Activity activity, String authHeader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CloudAdapterBase.ProcessActivityAsync(String authHeader, Activity activity, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.CloudAdapter.ProcessAsync(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse, IBot bot, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.EchoSkillBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync() in D:\\bot\\bot\\80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot\\EchoSkillBot\\Controllers\\BotController.cs:line 30
   at lambda_method4(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)`
```

I am not sure what valid audience configuration means here.

1. How do we make sure the configuration uses single tenant properly without going through the botframework route? Using this approach requires us to turn on the multi tenant support in the App authorization.
2. What valid audiences need to be provided and where can be configured?

Answer (score 0):

> How do we make sure the configuration uses single tenant properly
> without going through the botframework route? Using this approach
> requires us to turn on the multi tenant support in the App
> authorization.

Single tenant is not supported with Emulator
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned#managing-resources

What do you mean by "without going through the botframework route"?

Comment: Thanks Dana. What is the best way to debug single tenant bot service? Currently the Oauth URL points to Bot framework. If there a way to use the endpoints within the tenant. I would like to restrict the app registration to single tenant.